# Closing QMessageBox on timer, setText not showing

Tags: c++, qt, qmessagebox

The following piece of code closes my `QMessageBox` after 2 secs. But my text shows when the box is closing, It flashes really quick before the box closes. What is going on here?

```
 QMessageBox *msgBox = new QMessageBox();
 msgBox->setText("Coördinate is being created, please wait...");
 msgBox->show();
 QTimer::singleShot(2000, msgBox, SLOT(hide()));
```

[image]

This shows, and then just before closing I can see the text.

> update

Working in a single thread program: Method `WriteMultipleACLCommands()` is taking up a lot of time. Maybe thats the issue?

```
  QMessageBox *msgBox = new QMessageBox();
  msgBox->setText("Coördinate is being created, please wait...");
  msgBox->show();
  QTimer::singleShot(2000, msgBox, SLOT(hide()));
  singleton_SerialPortManager->WriteMultipleACLCommands();
  //function writes a few bytes onto a serial connection
```

Comment: I tried your code, and I don't see anything flashing. I'm using Qt 5.5.1 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: It doesn't look like there's anything wrong with that code. It's more likely to be something somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the update,

Of course it is an issue if you don't return from the calling function right away - you are blocking the event loop, hence updates to all widgets!

**Possible Solution**

You can make `WriteMultipleACLCommands` Q_INVOKABLE (or a slot) and invoke it as `Qt::QueuedConnection`:

`QMetaObject::invokeMethod(singleton_SerialPortManager, "WriteMultipleACLCommands", Qt::QueuedConnection);`

This way you just post an event to the events queue and return right away. After that the message box will receive an update, then, at some point `WriteMultipleACLCommands` will be called as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is fine, at least the part you are showing.
I tested it myself and it works without any problems.
But keep in mind, that closing and hiding the dialog are two different things.
You just hide the Window. The Window will still exist in memory.
Maybe you want to call the "close slot" in your timer and set the windows attribute to "delete on close":

```
QMessageBox *msgBox = new QMessageBox();
msgBox->setText("Coördinate is being created, please wait...");
msgBox->show();
msgBox->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
QTimer::singleShot(2000, msgBox, SLOT(close()));
```

If this isn't the cause of the effect you described, you have to give some more information.